# reloaddata() function closes tableview, and returns to be previous screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app with two screens (view controller and tableview) I am trying to reload data in my table view each time user updates a filter used on the data. For example, my array holds train schedule data, I filter this data based on direction.  The user updates the direction and then the tableview should reload based and update filter for direction.

I have tried to use 
    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }

I have function that is called by a button action to update direction

```
@IBAction func ChangeDirection(_ sender: Any) {
    changeDirection()
}

func changeDirection()
{
    if direction == "Southbound" {
        direction = "Northbound"
    }
    else {
        direction = "Southbound"
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
}
```

I use view controller with ui picker so user can select station they want train schedule on, the ui picker accesses a singleton class  that holds the train scheduled data for each station (I am wondering if this maybe the issue) maybe this needs to be accessed from tableview.

```
if segue.identifier == "Stations"
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? TableViewController
        let xmlParserSchedule = XMLParserSchedule()
        xmlParserSchedule.runScheudledParser(userStation:StationsDecoder.shared.uiStationsSorted[station])
        vc?.stationData=xmlParserSchedule.sortedArrival


    }
```

I expect the tableview to reload based on new direction selected by the user, however tableview is closed and we go back to view controller ui picker screen. When I debug step into code when calling reloaddata() I have noted the memory seems to leak infinitely.

I am adding complete code from viewcontroller and table view incase this is helpful:

view controller:
    import UIKit

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    //stores picker selection for array index in station data
    var station = 0
    //UI Picker Outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var UIStationPicker: UIPickerView!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //self.UIStationPicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKey: "textColor")
        self.UIStationPicker.delegate = self
        self.UIStationPicker.dataSource = self
        self.UIStationPicker.reloadAllComponents()

        //check if station file is already loaded by accessing the singletons/create plist throw method
        do {
            try? CreatePlist.shared.createPlist()
            //throw needed here to reach the catch block
            throw CreatePlist.ErrorsToThrow.fileAlreadyExists
        }catch {
            print("file already exists")
            print("time to get decoding")
            //decode the station plist using singleton class method
            StationsDecoder.shared.decoder()
            //get stations in array of dictionaries using singlton class method
            StationsDecoder.shared.getStations()
            self.UIStationPicker.reloadAllComponents()

        }
    }
    //uiPicker delegate methods
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Number of columns of data
    }
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) ->Int {
        return 1
    }
    // The number of rows of data
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int)-> Int {
        return StationsDecoder.shared.uiStationsSorted.count
    }
    // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int)-> String? {

        return StationsDecoder.shared.uiStationsSorted[row]
    }


    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, attributedTitleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> NSAttributedString? {
        let titleData = StationsDecoder.shared.uiStationsSorted[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData, attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 28.0)!,NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white])
        return myTitle
    }
    // Capture the picker view selection
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        station = row

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Stations", sender: Any?.self)

    }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){


    if segue.identifier == "Stations"
    {
        let vc = segue.destination as? TableViewController
        let xmlParserSchedule = XMLParserSchedule()
        xmlParserSchedule.runScheudledParser(userStation:StationsDecoder.shared.uiStationsSorted[station])
        vc?.stationData=xmlParserSchedule.sortedArrival


    }
        }



}
```

tableview

```
import UIKit

var direction:String = "Southbound"


class TableViewController: UITableViewController{

//this code here is interesting, it dismisses the presented view with orignally presented view ie tableview is replaced with initial view controller. this avoids calling dataload method again in view controller which can duplicate your data

@IBAction func GoBack(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func ChangeDirection(_ sender: Any) {
    changeDirection()
}

func changeDirection()
{
    if direction == "Southbound" {
        direction = "Northbound"
    }
    else {
        direction = "Southbound"
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}

//array of tuples to hold station data
var stationData: [(stationfullname:String,origin: String,destination:String,lastLocation: String, dueIn: Int, late: Int, due: Int, expArrival: String, direction: String) ] = []

//array literal, for tuples
//var data = [String:(stationfullname:String,origin: String,destination:String,lastLocation: String, dueIn: Int, late: Int, due: Int, expArrival: String, direction: String)].self



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // As long as `total` is the last case in our TableSection enum,
    // this method will always be dynamically correct no mater how many table sections we add or remove.
      return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

            return stationData.filter{($0.direction == direction)}.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

         return direction

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "StationLevel", for: indexPath)
           cell.textLabel?.text = stationData.filter{($0.direction == direction)}[indexPath.row].destination
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(String(stationData.filter{($0.direction == direction)}[indexPath.row].due)) mins"

    return cell
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think there is any need of DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() } instead of this direct call reloadData() and only of this code it hard to identify memory leak

Comment: thanks for rapid response, try reloadData() result is identical though.

Comment: try to call simple reloadData let me know is it solve or not.

Comment: hi Pravin that's what I meant above, (typo- sorry) meant to say  I tried simple reloadData, but it did not solve - got same result

Comment: Is it possible to put this code some where from where i can download and debug it.

Comment: Hi Parvin i have built the app with a ton of singleton classes, its quite a mess at the moment, is there anything you can suggest from looking at these two files as everything is working fine apart of the reload piece.

Comment: if it giving issue of infinite memory leak it means some func is calling again and again. You can check it call log. Mostly there some issue with singleton because these type of issue come with singleton. Another one is check how many tableview object created when you come back then your tableview should deinit

Comment: Thanks, not seeing anything in the console regarding memory, is there somewhere else should check?

Answer (score 0):

Oh Lordie,turns out I had an extra sent event for the button that was sending back to view controller, there is 4 hours I will never get back.
Thanks for the help regardless Parvin.